# No $PATH file in my home folder on my Ventura 13.5.2?

Tags: terminal, environment-variables

I am using zsh and I wanted to modify the $PATH variable permanently. I can't seem to find either `.zshrc` or `.zsh_profile` on my computer -- I tried searching in Finder with enabled hidden files.

I tried creating `.zshrc` in my home folder. Here is the full text of what I pasted there.

```
/Users/dnes/Library/Python/3.9/bin
```

I then made this file executable. Here is what I now see when opening Terminal:

```
Last login: Wed Sep 27 20:30:43 on ttys000
/Users/dnes/.zshrc:1: permission denied: /Users/dnes/Library/Python/3.9/bin
dnes@MacBook-Air-Denis ~ %
```

I also tried `echo $ZDOTDIR` to see where the file is. But the command only produced a blank line. Meanwhile `echo $PATH` produces a normal string of few paths divided by `:` as one normally expects.

I know that for one Terminal session I can use `export $PATH`. How do I nowadays modify my $PATH variable permanently?

Comment: Those files don't exist by default you have to actually create them yourself.

Comment: @mmmmmm Thank you for your comment. I did try creating my own .zshrc and .zsh_profile in my home folder. My zsh doesn't seem to read those files, as the paths I specified do not appear in $PATH.

Comment: What exactly is in your .zshrc and what is the full path to it?

Comment: @mmmmmm I have created .zshrc in the folder /Users/dnes/ and I have written "/Users/dnes/Library/Python/3.9/bin" there

Comment: Let us see the full text of the .zshrc and paste it in the question - your wording here suggests that what you have done will not work

Comment: @mmmmmm done, would you please look at it?

Comment: You don't just put the path in the file it needs to be valid zsh syntax which you know how to do as you show how in the last paragraph of your question. Just put the whol export statement you typed in the Termial into .zshrc and read the zsh docs which explain all this https://zsh.sourceforge.io/

Comment: For editors etc I have just fully read the duplicate I suggested and in general the answer is OK but when I think of all the details (which don't really apply to the OP) it is a bit too bash specific and the path_helper is not quite correct so a better duplicate should be used.

Comment: To be explicit, you could for example put this in your `.zshrc` file: `export PATH=/Users/dnes/Library/Python/3.9/bin:$PATH`.

Comment: @mmmmmm oh my god, it finally works. Many many thanks

Answer (score -1):

After some investigating I stumbled upon the folder `/etc/paths.d/` with one file containing part of my $PATH variable.

I created another file in this folder, put my paths in it, and now everything works. Not sure if that's the intended way to do it though.

Comment: These are for all users on the Mac and might get deleted when upgrade the OS. You should CREATE the files you mention in your question

Comment: @mmmmmm They don't get deleted (I have files in there which date back to 2019), but not all users might have access to `/Users/dnes/Library/Python/3.9/bin` so user-specific paths could still cause issues.